# Eigen matrix multiply triggers code to link to libomp.dll; it is already linked to libiomp5md.lib/dll. How do I stop this spurious linkage

Tags: c++, cmake, openmp, eigen3

A short complex piece of code is built with cmake; it links to Lapack(MKL), gmp/mpir, boost,.. and eigen3 (the versions are from vcpckg and the version of eigen is eigen3:x64-windows 3.3.9#1 ). I am currently testing it on Visual Studio 2019.

At first glance all is well and eigen does a fantastic job and commands like `Eigen::FullPivLU<MatrixXS> B_lu(B);` work perfectly with dynamic eigen matrices (500 dimensional) with boost multi-precision rational coefficients.

However, as soon as my code includes the line `B*x;`, build is still error free but the executable makes an immediate and inappropriate runtime request for libomp.dll and then crashes as I do not have it available. I cannot have it available as I am linking to  the intel libiomp5md.lib and dll. Looking at the cmake cache I see  `BLAS_libiomp5md_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/lib/libiomp5md.lib`

Suggestions to get this working would be appreciated.